# Good Learning Sources to learn ERD and ORM

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, erd

I have created Entity Relationship Diagrams and going to learn JPA now. I want to smooth my skill of ER diagrams according to DB requirements more and learn more about Object Relational Mappings up to an expert level. Involving in real project development may increase my ORM knowledge and experience. (Currently what I do is, just think and draw and no one to guide me.
) But I d like to have good learning sources for a better knowledge, experience in database designing, ERD, ORM s .  I request from all you experts any links,samples, books which may help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the reason for Down vote?

Comment: [read this to understand why you got a downvote (not from me), or why this will be closed](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[small tutorial](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:8n-O8zlDoBEJ%3ahttps://www.site.uottawa.ca/~tcl/seg4210/coursenotes/PdfsForTopicsPostMT/TopicO17-ObjectRelationalMapping.pdf+&hl=en&gl=lk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgdOz6bmuqJYxAVeFdSacHWl3OWh-um9G-2rioN8hJK_L4NumxPhx7gJjc6E-VqEsOL0S47s705pLS9GmxjsdX4aWhbqGHPE-Oo9aBEUop4XOfhhYShrhrniLSlwBE6sJEFjOoW&sig=AHIEtbRBRu_ym5nMHYH42kYed7_2Ot3xfQ&pli=1)

Also sample images can be found on google image search.

Also [Here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

Answer (score 2):

I guess experts are experts because they have experience, and the experience comes from creating bad ERDs. So I would rather keep doing what you are doing. Select very large system which is hard to tackle by single person try to make a bad design and then iterate.

A quick search shows plenty of different sources on Google, Try to find write ups by `Wrox` or `O'Relly` they both are really good at explaining programming technologies.

Comment: Thanks Owl. I ll see their publishing s.